# Failed to customize PFLogInViewController with Parse iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I used Parse to implement login/signup function for my app. I customized PFLogInViewController and PFSignUpViewController's appearance with the following code.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
        self.loginVC.fields = PFLogInFields(rawValue: PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword.rawValue | PFLogInFields.LogInButton.rawValue |
            PFLogInFields.SignUpButton.rawValue | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten.rawValue | PFLogInFields.DismissButton.rawValue | PFLogInFields.Facebook.rawValue)

        var logInLogoTitle = UILabel()
        logInLogoTitle.text = "My custom title"
        self.loginVC.logInView?.logo = logInLogoTitle
        self.loginVC.delegate = self
        self.loginVC.facebookPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

        var signupLogoTitle = UILabel()
        signupLogoTitle.text = "Create new account"
        self.signupVC.signUpView?.logo = signupLogoTitle
        self.signupVC.delegate = self
        self.loginVC.signUpController = self.signupVC

    }
}
```

I also created a login button and added the following func as its target so when it gets pressed the PFLogInViewController will be presented.

```
func loginPressed() {
    self.presentViewController(self.loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem is whenever I ran the program again on the simulator or my iPhone after it was launched for the first time, PFLogInViewController and PFSignUpViewController's appearance would both turn into the default look (with the big "Parse" label and default login options). I have to delete the app on the simulator or my iPhone to make the customized view controllers appear. Does anyone know what exactly went wrong here?